# Retry requests mechanism

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib3

Im trying to build web **scraper** project
one of the thing im trying to do is smart retry mechanism
using urlib3 and requests and beautiful soup

when im set the timeout=1
in order to fail the retry and check retry its break with exception
code below :

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import time
import sys
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util import Retry

# this get_items methods is for getting dict of link to scrape items per link

def get_items(self, dict):
        itemdict = {}
        for k, v in dict.items():
            boolean = True
        # here, we fetch the content from the url, using the requests library
            while (boolean):
             try:
                a =requests.Session()
                retries = Retry(total=3, backoff_factor=0.1, status_forcelist=[301,500, 502, 503, 504])
                a.mount(('https://'), HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
                page_response = a.get('https://www.XXXXXXX.il' + v, timeout=1)
             except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
                print  ("Timeout occurred")
                logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
             else:
                 boolean = False

            # we use the html parser to parse the url content and store it in a variable.
            page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
            for i in page_content.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'prodPrice'}):
                parent = i.parent.parent.contents[0]
                getparentfunc= parent.find("a", attrs={"href": "javascript:void(0)"})
                itemid = re.search(".*'(\d+)'.*", getparentfunc.attrs['onclick']).groups()[0]
                itemName = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', i.parent.contents[0].text)
                priceitem = re.sub(r'[\D.]+ ', ' ', i.text)
                itemdict[itemid] = [itemName, priceitem]
```

ill be appreciate for efficiency retry mechanism resolve or any other simple method
Thanks
Iso

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like:

```
def get(url, retries=3):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        return r
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
        if retries < 1:
            raise ValueError('No more retries!')
        return get(href, retries - 1)
```